# language and framework of choice for iPad development for music sequencer

Tags: c++, ios, openframeworks, synthesizer

I need to create a music sequencer for the iPad but have no experience yet on this platform. I have several questions about this subject, hopefully I can find some answers here.

- OpenFrameworks seems to be the way to go for this kind of things. I want my application to be able to play both synth sounds and samples. Are both of those things possible with oF? Any suggestions/alternatives?
- Does iOS have some sort of alternative to the android NDK? I don't have any experience with Objective C but I do know some C++ and I would like to do as much as possible in that language. Is it possible to do the 'heavy' work in C++ and only do the views etc. in Objective C?
- Are there any free sample packs that I could use for my sounds? I'm only looking for basic instruments like guitar, bass, drums and maybe a piano.

Any other suggestions or tips you might have are welcome!

Comment: iOS has X-Code, I think now it's a free download even if you do not have an Apple developer account. You should be able to edit C++ in there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OpenFrameworks seems to be the way to go for this kind of things. I want my application to be able to play both synth sounds and samples. Are both of those things possible with oF? Any suggestions/alternatives?

As of iOS 5, you can use MusicSequence and MusicPlayer APIs for MIDI. Then you can use AUSampler for sample playback.

> Does iOS have some sort of alternative to the android NDK? I don't have any experience with Objective C but I do know some C++ and I would like to do as much as possible in that language. Is it possible to do the 'heavy' work in C++ and only do the views etc. in Objective C?

For realtime audio, ObjC is not an option. C++ and C are the common langs in this domain.

> Are there any free sample packs that I could use for my sounds? I'm only looking for basic instruments like guitar, bass, drums and maybe a piano.

Yes. First, you should choose your sample/map format. Then see what the musicians recommend for free samples - [www.kvraudio.com](http://www.kvraudio.com) would be a good place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use openFrameworks. I would go with openFrameworks too, because its cross-platform. you can even deploy your software to mac, linux, windows and android too!

There are several music sequencer apps written in openFrameworks out there, for example: http://nodebeat.com/

You can look here to find even more (iOS) apps built with openFrameworks: http://forum.openframeworks.cc/

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with frameworks, but you can freely mix objective-C and c/c++.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Objective C is a superset of ANSI C, the Objective C tools and environment includes a built-in C NDK.

Answer (score 0):

OpenFrameworks isn't really a good solution for this. None of the libs I have tested are very feature complete or well tested and there are too many hacks/bugs involved.

If you are targeting iOS5 then you can use the [MusicPlayer API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicPlayerServices_Reference/Reference/reference.html) It is very easy to use, can handle loading soundFonts, load and save midi files, create tracks on the fly, etc. It is all C/C++ and just your UI needs to be on ObjC.

Oh, I've used Bass and it is pretty good for pre iOS5 targets.

Comment: This seems to be only for sample playback though. Or is it possible to create synths with this as well?

Comment: MusicPlayer is an API for midi playback - from file or notes on the fly. It will use whatever AudioUnit you specify - using a soundFont or a synth. If you are looking for a pure synth for iOS MobileSynth is one solution: http://code.google.com/p/mobilesynth/ Or check out audioGraph - great demo code: http://zerokidz.com/audiograph/Home.html

Comment: I'm actually looking for both synth and sample playback (and sometimes I will need to do them simultaneously, for example playing a four to the floor kick sample and a synth over it). Targeting only iOS5 is not a problem. If I understand correctly, I can use MusicPlayer for soundFont (samples) and something like audioGraph together? Thanks for your help. I'm having many problems with OF so I'm stil undecided.